# Renaming Dropbox app folder?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

When a Dropbox user connects to a single folder Dropbox app (let's call it Foo), Dropbox creates a new app folder like so:

> Dropbox > Apps > Foo

If the user changes the name of folder *Foo* to something else, will Foo (the app) still be able to access its contents?

I haven't been able to find documentation about what happens when a user renames an app folder. From my own testing, everything seems to still work but I'd like confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the user renames the app folder, the app will continue to work and be able to access the contents of the app folder. The app won't even know about the change, and doesn't need to do anything special to handle it. (This is much like how a user can rename a shared folder: https://www.dropbox.com/help/64 )